# Create 301 for Joomla K2 to Shopify Blog

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, k2

We have moved to a Shopify site for our cart and moving all other data across. I'm trying to create 301 redirects for our K2 blog content and struggling.

Using the Joomla Redirects (image) for all blog posts still won't redirect. I've created new blog pages in Shopify.

Version Joomla! 3.3.3 Stable [ Ember ] 25-July-2014 13:00 GMT
PHP Version 5.6.40

[image]

Comment: Welcome to JSE. While you wait for support, please take the [tour].